# EF5 Mapping IQueryable to custom class with Column Attributes

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, iqueryable, entity-framework-5

Okay so here is the problem, I have got a view in the database that contains a-lot of information, 100ish columns, vwComponantA

I have an entity within my .net app called ComponantA which contains all the mappings using [Column()] attributes, that fine, that works, but is slow because it does a select * on the DB to populate the object, again this works.

To get around the performance issues of above I introduced DynamicLinq. This allows me to cut down the amount of columns I bring back and still allows me to use type safety to dow querying using normal Linq which is great. To then deal with the cut down field I bring back I have seperate POCO componants, each with there own set of [Column] attributes on that get mapped at run time using a mapping class.

The problem is that mapping between these can be quite slow when dealing with large datasets, 10000 records maps 10000 times etc. What EF does is to create a DynamicProxyClass that you then map between your component.

My question is, how can I avoid the mapping and let EF do the mapping for me? (I am dealing with `IQueryable` NOT `IQueryable<T>` because of dynamic linq)

There has to be a way to leverage the [Column] attributes whilst keeping the query dynamic.

This is all code first and entity framework 5.

Thanks for any help. Nick

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I don't understand your question but what you are trying to do doesn't need dynamic linq. You just need projections:

```
var data = from c in context.vwComponentA
           select new POCOWithIdAndName {
               Id = c.Id,
               Name = c.Name
           };
```

The projection is executed in database so it will bring back only `Id` and `Name`.

Comment: The reason I have this is because there are certain rules in which column I select for a particular type. i.e. there is 5 columns on the view that all represent something but only one I want to be mapped back to a generic property on my object. Does this make sense?

Comment: I still don't understand why it should be a problem with projection where you explicitly say which column is assigned to which property.

Comment: Okay so the reason I use DynamicSQL is for example I have a view with 5 columns, they all have a similar meaning, but depending on what a user chooses through a UI, one of them needs to be mapped back to a property called 'Outcome', this property then drives a lot of logic. So its not as simple as "Outcome = c.Outcome", its more like "Outcome = c.<Property to be determined at runtime>". I guess the question is, how can I do this with what you propose above? (Ive probably confused you more - let me throw some stuff on zerobin)

Comment: http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?74e9753519d18029#nDO/jSN0dHcF5+tO0L2E/NeqfkSY3G0TTWTcds/eQ/8=